# Merge two SELECT with different WHERE in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to merge this two queries?

```
SELECT * FROM OFF WHERE New = 0 AND Saw = 1 AND El = 0
SELECT * FROM OFF WHERE New = 1 AND Saw = 0 AND El = 0
```

If I use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM OFF WHERE New = 0 AND Saw = 1 AND El = 0 AND New = 1 AND Saw = 0 AND El = 0
```

I have obviously others result as expected.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

use `OR` when grouping these conditions,

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `OFF`
WHERE  (New = 0 AND Saw = 1 AND El = 0) OR 
       (New = 1 AND Saw = 0 AND El = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always merge any two queries using UNION

```
(SELECT * FROM OFF WHERE New = 0 AND Saw = 1 AND El = 0)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM OFF WHERE New = 1 AND Saw = 0 AND El = 0)
```